# Cakephp Search Plugin filterArgs (if else in array)

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, search, model

I want to make an if else in `filterArgs` (in Model) as follow:

```
public $filterArgs = array(
            array('name' => 'to', 'type' => 'value' => 'Product.regular_price' ),
        );
```

I want the field to change base on the condition.

> if sale = 1, field is promo_price, else field is regular_price

I already try below code (but unsuccessful):

```
'field'=> 'Product.sale' => 1 ? 'Product.promo_price >=' : 'Product.regular_price >='
```

Can someone please help me. Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a virtualField in my Product Model

```
$virtualFields = array 
(
    'my_price' => 'IF(Product.sale = 1, Product.promo_price, Product.regular_price)';
)

public $filterArgs = array
(
    'my_price' => array('type' => 'value'),
);
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain 'from' => 'IF(Product.sale = 1, Product.promo_price, Product.regular_price)',
so far, no error. but the result somehow wrong.

Comment: Instead of creating the IF in php I created it in mysql using virtualFields. I created a new column named `my_price` wich value is `promo_price` rather than `regular_price` based on `sale` column vale. Then I filter results by `my_price` value